# Loop through Laravel eloquent relationship in controller

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-7

I have two models with relationship methods,

Product

```
 public function facts()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Fact');
}
```

Facts

```
public function products()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Product');
}
```

I'm trying to get access to relationship column name and loop through it

```
$product = Product::where('slug', 'some-slug')->with('facts')->get();
```

this works but how to select a column called 'name' and loop through it? I have tried

```
foreach($products as $product){
     $sum = $facts->name;
  }
dd{$sum}

Exception: Property [name] does not exist on this collection instance
```

Comment: try `$sum = $products->facts()->name;`

Comment: @Daniel if any answer's your question go ahead and accept it

Answer (score 0):

Since it's a `hasMany` relationship, you can [pluck](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections#method-pluck) `name` from the `collection`

```
foreach ($product as $products) {
   $sum = implode('', $products->facts->pluck('name')->toArray());
   dd($sum);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to pull the `name` field from a collection of `facts`, which won't have a property for that whole collection called `name`.  You can use two loops.   Example at the simplest level:

```
foreach ($product as $products) {
  foreach($products->facts as $fact){
        $sum = $facts->name;
        echo $sum;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure where you have this variable from but you are not using the iterator in your `foreach` loop:

```
foreach($products->facts as $fact){
    $sum = $facts->name;
}
```

What is `$facts`? It sounds like it is a Collection. Also what is `$products`, you created `$product`. You want to be using `$fact` the current iterated Fact for this Product:

```
$product = Product::where(....)->('facts')->first();

foreach ($product->facts as $fact) {
    ...
    $something = $fact->name;
    ...
}
```